# Preview Latex files IntelliJ (Idea, PyCharm..)

Tags: intellij-idea, latex

How to preview latex (.tex) files in IntelliJ like at https://www.sharelatex.com/ ?

Comment: have you tried this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7660-latex ?

Comment: @Andrey I installed it but I don't know how to make it work(I can't find the "Preview" button)

Comment: @sleepyhead, same, did you have any luck with it?

Comment: @aadibajpai Nope, still looking for a better solution, but in the meanwhile I am using overleaf.com

Comment: @sleepyhead same, but one of my projects uses LaTeX files so it would've been nice if there was some way native to PyCharm. Overleaf is great though

Comment: what about with markdown?

Comment: @CharlieParker markdown is wonderful but basic in comparison to Latex and for scientific papers Latex is a defacto default. I was writing a paper so that is why

Comment: @sleepyhead do you know if latex is displayable in markdown in Pycharm (or a jetbrain product)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try the [TeXiFy](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9473-texify-idea) plugin. The full instructions to compile `.tex` (LaTeX) files are in the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA#installation-instructions-and-getting-started).

A *very* short summary of those instructions in the case you know what you're doing:

1. Install a LaTeX distribution and IntelliJ, then install the TeXiFy plugin and restart IntelliJ.
2. You can compile `.tex` files using the button which appears next to the `\begin{document}` line.

[Edit] Automatic compilation is also supported: https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Automatic-compilation

Comment: Hey, thank you for suggestion I did use it once before, but unfortunately it is not supported on the latest versions of JetBrains products, and I think it doesn't do live previews, am I correct?

Comment: @sleepyhead That has been fixed in the last version 0.6.3 which was uploaded six days ago, now all latest Jetbrains products are supported. Aha, now you ask a different question! Because to **preview** (like in your question) a file is just to **compile** it, but **live preview** is something different! If you want support for **continuous compiling** please create an issue at https://github.com/Ruben-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/issues so it can be discussed there, I don't know a quick fix at the moment. Essentially it involves running the run configuration continuously, which should be doable.

Comment: PS Next time you ask a LaTeX-related question, consider asking it at https://tex.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes, what about markdown? You can view markdown files in IntelliJ using a markdown plugin (there are several, one built-in). Or if you are asking how to write markdown inside LaTeX files, look here: https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Language-injection

Comment: @PHPirate what I am asking is how to write latex files in markdown AND have them preview beautifully in pycharm (or a jetbrains product). Is this possible?

Comment: @CharlieParker Good question, that would be functionality that a markdown plugin needs to provide, so I don't know that off-hand - best to ask a new question for that. The [Markdown Navigator](https://github.com/vsch/idea-multimarkdown) mentions LaTeX but it's a paid plugin.